# How to annotate a function where the types of some of the parameters are interdependent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I want to annotate a function where the type of one parameter determines the type of another and different combinations are possible (this function happens to be the `__init__` method of a class). It seems that [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) (see also the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#function-overloading)) is suited for that use case, however, in addition to the two interdependent parameters, the `__init__` method has about 20 other parameters with types not dependent on the first two parameters.

Consider the following example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import overload
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias


# The following types are arbitrary, but the important detail is
# that they are all different.
A: TypeAlias = str
B: TypeAlias = int
C: TypeAlias = list
D: TypeAlias = tuple


class Example:
    @overload
    def __init__(self, x: A, y: B): ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, x: C, y: D): ...

    def __init__(
        self,
        x,
        y,
        *,
        foo: str,
        bar: str,
        option: str = '',
        # ... 20 more optional parameters follow ...
    ):
        pass  # do something
```

Here, `mypy` complains that the implementation of `__init__` contains more parameters than the overloaded versions:

```
test.py:20: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 1
test.py:20: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2
```

If I repeat all other parameters, `foo, bar, option, ...`, in the overloaded versions, then mypy does not complain. This, however, adds a lot of visual noise to the overloaded definitions and it isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), either.

Hence, I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid that repetition while specifying the interdependence of the two parameters `x` and `y`.

Comment: Maybe rethink the interface -- if `x` and `y` are interdependent, maybe they should be a single tuple instead of two independent args?  Then you can simply type them as `tuple[A, B] | tuple[C, D]` and not have to do any `overload`ing at all.

Comment: "If I repeat all other parameters, foo, bar, option, ..., in the overloaded versions, then mypy does not complain. This, however, adds a lot of visual noise to the overloaded definitions and it isn't DRY, either." yeah, but that's really your only option. The fundamental problem seems to be the number of parameters and the way they vary

Comment: @Samwise This is a good suggestion. While at first it feels awkward to use a wrapping tuple, it does convey the extra information that these two parameters are really interdependent and thus they need to go together.

Comment: This is why we want [`TypedDict` for `**kwargs` annotation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/)! PEP692 is still draft, but looks like a way to go. You'll have an option to do `**kwargs: **MyKwargs` then

Comment: I disagree that PEP692 is applicable here and I have to admit I am not a big fan of it either. But that is for a different discussion. I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga that `@overload` is _exactly_ the way to go. The fact that you have to repeat yourself has to do with the rules that were defined for overloading function signatures. You may not like it, but that is how it is. I also think that a function with 20 parameters is at least worth reflecting on... The amount of confusion added by different interdependent types is also questionable.